# Not able to perform migration in Rails 6 due to an error in trackable in devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mysql2

I'm getting an error while doing the migration telling duplicate column names which I'm not able to figure out since I'm new to rails.some help would be appreciated. It says that I've done something wrong on the 3rd line of the trackable file which I've given below. previously it showed an error in the 6th line of the confirmable file, but now it's pointing different file.

**error**

```
 == 20210817054855 AddTrackableToDevise: migrating =============================
    -- add_column(:users, :sign_in_count, :integer, {:default=>0, :null=>false})
    rails aborted!
    StandardError: An error has occurred, all later migrations canceled:
    
    Mysql2::Error: Duplicate column name 'sign_in_count'
    /home/user/ruby_projects/ruby_auth/authapp/db/migrate/20210817054855_add_trackable_to_devise.rb:3:in `up'
    /home/user/ruby_projects/ruby_auth/authapp/bin/rails:5:in `<top (required)>'
    /home/user/ruby_projects/ruby_auth/authapp/bin/spring:10:in `block in <top (required)>'
    /home/user/ruby_projects/ruby_auth/authapp/bin/spring:7:in `<top (required)>'
    
    Caused by:
    ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: Mysql2::Error: Duplicate column name 'sign_in_count'
    /home/user/ruby_projects/ruby_auth/authapp/db/migrate/20210817054855_add_trackable_to_devise.rb:3:in `up'
    /home/user/ruby_projects/ruby_auth/authapp/bin/rails:5:in `<top (required)>'
    /home/user/ruby_projects/ruby_auth/authapp/bin/spring:10:in `block in <top (required)>'
    /home/user/ruby_projects/ruby_auth/authapp/bin/spring:7:in `<top (required)>'
    
    Caused by:
    Mysql2::Error: Duplicate column name 'sign_in_count'
    /home/user/ruby_projects/ruby_auth/authapp/db/migrate/20210817054855_add_trackable_to_devise.rb:3:in `up'
    /home/user/ruby_projects/ruby_auth/authapp/bin/rails:5:in `<top (required)>'
    /home/user/ruby_projects/ruby_auth/authapp/bin/spring:10:in `block in <top (required)>'
    /home/user/ruby_projects/ruby_auth/authapp/bin/spring:7:in `<top (required)>'
    Tasks: TOP => db:migrate
    (See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

**confirmable file**

```
class AddConfirmableToDevise < ActiveRecord::Migration[6.1]
  def up
    add_column :users, :confirmation_token, :string
    add_column :users, :confirmed_at, :datetime
    add_column :users, :confirmation_sent_at, :datetime
    add_column :users, :unconfirmed_email, :string # Only if using reconfirmable
    add_index :users, :confirmation_token, unique: true
    # User.reset_column_information # Need for some types of updates, but not for update_all.
    # To avoid a short time window between running the migration and updating all existing
    # users as confirmed, do the following
    User.update_all confirmed_at: DateTime.now
    # All existing user accounts should be able to log in after this.
  end

  def down
    remove_index :users, :confirmation_token
    remove_columns :users, :confirmation_token, :confirmed_at, :confirmation_sent_at
    remove_columns :users, :unconfirmed_email # Only if using reconfirmable
  end
end
```

**trackable file**

```
class AddTrackableToDevise < ActiveRecord::Migration[6.1]
  def up
    add_column :users, :sign_in_count, :integer, default: 0, null: false
    add_column :users, :current_sign_in_at, :datetime
    add_column :users, :last_sign_in_at, :datetime
    add_column :users, :current_sign_in_ip, :inet
    add_column :users, :last_sign_in_ip, :inet
  end

  def down
    remove_columns :users, :sign_in_count, :current_sign_in_at, :last_sign_in_at, :current_sign_in_ip, :last_sign_in_ip
  end
end
```

Comment: Could add `unless column_exists?(:users, :sign_in_count)` as a trailing conditional. Just modify the second argument for each column you need to conditionally add. https://apidock.com/rails/v5.2.3/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/SchemaStatements/column_exists%3F

Comment: @Int'lManOfCodingMystery    getting an error again ,but different`Mysql2::Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'inet'`

Comment: I am unfamiliar with MySQL, but it would appear that the column type you're trying to use is not available on the version of your mysql